# Перемещение файлов по массиву

Tags: c#, массивы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в массиве есть полные пути к файлам и нужно, что бы перемещались файлы из заданного массива в `newPath`. Как это можно реализовать?

```
string[] NewFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Test1\1.cfg", System.Text.Encoding.Default);
string newPath = @"С:\Test2\";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цикл `foreach` по массиву путей с последующем вызовом `File.Move` на каждом элементе массива. 
Вторым аргументом в `File.Move` передаешь `Path.Combine(newPath,Path.GetFileName (элемент массива))`

Comment: Значит получается первым аргументом выступает элемент массива?

Comment: Как-то так. Я бы еще try/catch добавил бы.

Comment: Так, окей, как быть если пишет "FileNotFoundException" ?)

Comment: @Jeronwen, очевидно, что файл, который ты хочешь перенести из одного места в другое, его нет в исходном месте.

Comment: Ну это логично, но файл есть - значит скорее всего проблема в правах.

Comment: Спасибо огромное)